# Datomic - automatically retract missing component entities

Tags: datomic

I have a nested structure (that can also be deeply nested). All nested entities are marked as components. Creation works just fine.

```
{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user)
 :tree/name "some tree"
 :tree/nodes [{:node/name "Node1"
               :node/prop "some prop"}
              {:node/name "Node2"
               :node/prop "another prop"}]}
```

Let's say the tree above is created. I pull it for an update and it looks like this:

```
{:db/id 1
 :tree/name "some tree"
 :tree/nodes [{:db/id 2
               :node/name "Node1"
               :node/prop "some prop"}
              {:db/id 3
               :node/name "Node2"
               :node/prop "another prop"}]}
```

From the UI I remove the first node:

```
{:db/id 1
 :tree/name "some tree"
 :tree/nodes [{:db/id 3
               :node/name "Node2"
               :node/prop "another prop"}]}
```

How do I automatically remove the node with db/id 2? The only thing I can think of is pulling the nodes and comparing them to the nodes that I'm submitting. Because the structure can be nested more deeply I will need to traverse the collection recursively. Is there a more automatic way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in transaction function `retractEntity` will recursively retract component entities:

http://docs.datomic.com/transactions.html#dbfn-retractentity

Comment: This solves the recursion, thanks. However I still need to compare the first level nodes for differences manually. I honestly hoped for something more automatic or built in.